# I have Select count some table row, but there is number '1' that shows behind counting number? Why?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I just want to Count data from table row. This is code. It works, somehow..
    // Query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(answer) as ans FROM answers WHERE  questionId = '$id' ");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
echo  $row['ans'];

}
```

With this code, it count me thing that i want But, behing counting number there is number '1' that shows up. So ih i have 5 answers for specific question, it shows me '51'. Why?

Comment: execute the query manually and see the data in mysql. and decide where the error exist. By seeing your code there is no problem here

Comment: search "1" in your code ... you can find culprit ...:)

Comment: I never has that number 1 , until i inserted that select count code...

Comment: @bobouch look my edit.

Answer (score 0):

this code will never echo 1.

look your code where are you echoing something that comes with 1.

you are echoing something that comes with 1 exactly after this code